# jQuery methods in $.ajax success handler don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent

I have a function:

```
$(".delete").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "ServerHandler.ashx",
        data: "mode=delete&item=" + $(this).attr("title"),
        success: function() {
            $(this).parent().parent().remove();
            alert("hi");
        }
    });
});​
```

I have a problem when I delete the parent object. It just does not disappear. I tried to hide - did not help.
Alert is called normal.
How to solve?

Sorry for bad English.

Comment: Have you checked that there are no errors in your JS console? Also, make sure you're setting this up inside a domready event - otherwise the event handler may not register.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're inside another function with another `this` value by default. Pass the `this` value from the outer function with the `$.ajax` function as follows:

```
$.ajax({
  context: this,
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the `this` in the ajax success callback function is different from the click callback function. You could cache it to a local variable or use the `$.ajax()`'s `context` option.

```
$(".delete").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: "ServerHandler.ashx",
        data: "mode=delete&item=" + $this.attr("title"),
        success: function () {
            $this.parent().parent().remove();
            alert("hi");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the `context: this,` parameter in the ajax function.

When the success handler fires, the value of `this` won't be the same as it was before hand.

See here fore more: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".delete").click(function() {
    $object = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: "ServerHandler.ashx",
        data: "mode=delete&item=" + $(this).attr("title"),
        success: function() {
            $object.parent().parent().remove();
            alert("hi");
        }
    });
});​
```